# Removing labels from inset areas within main data frame

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, data-frame

I have three inset maps (separate data frames) within my map. I want to not label the buildings within the inset map extent on the main data frame, but keep labels outside of the inset extent. If it can remain dynamic, that would be perfect.

This is for ArcMap.

Comment: Just convert labels to features, using outline in cartography toolset.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to add an attribute to the buildings. An integer like LabelFlag where 0 is off, and 1 is on. On the main map only display labels where LabelFlag = 1, on the inset maps show all labels or just points where LabelFlag = 0.

There's no way to make this dynamic as far as I know.

You could play around with the Maplex options, but in my experience the attribute will be faster.

ArcGIS Pro may have some better options.